# Mean Value theorem: showing an equation has a solution

Tags: calculus

$g(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0,\pi]$ and differentiable on $(0,\pi)$ with $g(0)=g(\pi)$. I need to show that the equation $g'(x)+g(x)cos(x)=0$ has a solution in $(0,\pi)$.

*Attempt at Solution*:

Let $f(x)=k(x)g(x)$ for a suitable $k(x)$. Then $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$, and differentiable on $(0,\pi)$.

By the mean value theorem, there exists $c \in (0,\pi)$ such that
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(\pi)-f(0)}{\pi-0}=\frac{k(\pi)g(\pi)-k(0)g(0)}{\pi-0}=0$$

Now, $$f'(x)=k'(x)g(x)+k(x)g'(x)$$ so $$f'(c)=k'(c)g(c)+k(c)g'(c)=0$$

So I have $$k'(c)g(c)+k(c)g'(c)=0$$ and $$cos(c)g(c)+g'(c)=0$$

So I want to make $cos(c)=k'(c)$ and $k(c)=1$

Is there anyway to solve this? Or have I made a mistake earlier on?

Comment: I don't understand in your solution attempt, why $f'(c) = 0$. Is it given that $g(0) = g(\pi) = 0$, or just $g(0) = g(\pi)$?

Comment: I think maybe that's where I've gone wrong then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $F(x)=g(x)e^{sin(x)}$, observe that $F(0)=F(\pi)$ and $F'(x)=(g'(x)+g(x)\cos(x))e^{\sin(x)}$ now apply Rolle's theorem to $F$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x)$ is non-zero in $[0,π]$:

Let $h(x)=ln(g(x)+sinx$ ,defined in $[0,π]$.
$h$ is continuous on the closed interval and differentiable on the open one.

Check that $h(0)=h(π)$ and apply Rolle's theorem for $h$. There exists $ξ$ in $(0,π)$ such that $h'(ξ)=0$.

Just evaluate $h'(x)$ and you are done.